# I want to display post in wordpress, post1 floatLeft,post2 floatRight?

Tags: php, wordpress

![enter image description here][1]

" id="post-">

"rel="bookmark">

```
<div class="storyContent"><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></div>
```

```
<?php if($counter%2 == 0){ echo "<div class='clear'></div>";} ?>

<?php $counter++; ?>
```

and this is style.css

.floatRight {

float:right;

}

.floatLeft {

float:left;

}

.clear {

clear:both;

}

i want to display my post in this way please any one help to solve it dude..

post1
      post2
post3
       post4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
$p=1;
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
    $class = ($p%2 == 0) ? "float-right" : "float-left";
    $p++;
    // Use $class in the div class
}
```

Comment: i am not getting sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose for float left/right, you can do something like this:
`<p>` can be anything ... `<div>` ... `<table>` ...

CSS

```
.pright{float:right;}
.pleft{float:left;}
```

HTML

```
 <p class="pleft">
    post1
    thumbnail   content
  </hr>
  </p>
 <p class="pright">
    post2
    thumbnail   content
  </hr>
  </p>
```

Comment: i want to display dynamically through the post

Comment: I supose your looking for http://heinencreative.com/tutorials/adding-columns-to-a-wordpress-template , "Adding columns to a WordPress template"